# How to prepare request in POST method in Android where two parameters are only Strings where another is JSON object?

Tags: android, json

Here session_key and user_id are strings. While ' search_data' is json.

I have used the namevalue pairs and json object. But while i m combining below request, it is not working together.

I want to create request for below Request :

**session_key=71589h9f0ad7a830078a16706569fdee&search_data={"FavoritesUserID":"137","count":6,"start_index":-1,"subcat_id":["12","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","62","63"]}&user_id=137**

While i am executing above request , i am getting below error all time:

Missing Parameters IN request.

can any one please help me out with proper request where first 2 parameters are only string while other is JSON Object object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to choose one type of parameters.

Either wrap all you parameters data as a json:

```
{
   "height":26,
   "age":21,
   "data":
   {
     "ID":2173.
     ....
   }
}
```

or treat all your parameters as strings by simply giving the json data a parameter name:

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", createRequest.toString()));

Comment: I want to create HTTPPOST request:----   session_key=71589h9f0ad7a830078a16706569fdee&search_data={"FavoritesUserID":"137","count":6,"start_index":-1,"subcat_id":["12","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","62","63"]}&user_id=137

Comment: encode the json data: URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(), "ISO-8859-1") , and send as a regular param